# Subsetting datatable based on consecutive difference of dates

Tags: r, data-cleaning

**Preamble:**
The main problem is how to subset a datatable based on IDs, forming subsets within an ID based on consecutive time differences. A hint regarding this would be most welcome.

**The complete question/setup:**
I have a dataset `dt` in data.table format that looks like

```
  date       id val1 val2
  %d.%m.%Y
1 01.01.2000  1   5    10
2 09.01.2000  1   4     9
3 01.08.2000  1   3     8
4 01.01.2000  2   2     7
5 01.01.2000  3   1     6
6 14.01.2000  3   7     5
7 28.01.2000  3   8     4
8 01.06.2000  3   9     3
```

I want to combine observations (grouped by `id`) which are not more than two weeks apart (consecutively from observation to observation). By combining I mean that for each subset, I

- keep the value of the last observation of `val1`
- replace `val2` of the last observation with the sum of all values of `val2` of the group
- add `counter` for how many observations came together in this group.

I.e., I want to end up with a dataset like this

```
  date       id val1 val2 counter
  %d.%m.%Y
2 09.01.2000  1   4    19       2
3 01.08.2000  1   3     8       1
4 01.01.2000  2   2     7       1
7 28.01.2000  3   8    15       3
8 01.06.2000  3   9     3       1
```

Still, I am trying to wrap my head around data.table functions, particularly .SD and want to solve the issue with these tools.

So far I know

- that I can indicate what I mean by first and last using `setkey(dt,date)`
- that I can replace the last `val2` of a subset with the sum
  `dt[, val2 := replace(val2, .N, sum(val2[-.N], na.rm = TRUE)), by=id]`
- that I get the length of a subset with `[.N]`
- how to delete rows
- that I can calculate the difference between two dates with `difftime(strptime(dt$date[1],format ="%d.%m.%Y"),strptime(dt$date[2],format ="%d.%m.%Y"),units="weeks")`

However I can't get my head around how to subset the observations such that each subset contains only groups of observations of the same `id` with dates of (consecutive) distance at max 2 weeks.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `cumsum()` on a condition. In this case, the condition is being more than 14 days. When the condition is true, the cumulative sum increments.

```
df %>%
  mutate(rownumber = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(interval = as.numeric(as.Date(date, format = "%d.%m.%Y") - as.Date(lag(date), format = "%d.%m.%Y"))) %>%
  mutate(interval = ifelse(is.na(interval), 0, interval)) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(interval > 14) + 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  summarise(
    rownumber = last(rownumber),
    date = last(date),
    val1 = last(val1),
    val2 = sum(val2),
    counter = n()
  ) %>%
  select(rownumber, date, id, val1, val2, counter)
```

Output

```
  rownumber date          id  val1  val2 counter
      <int> <chr>      <int> <int> <int>   <int>
1         2 09.01.2000     1     4    19       2
2         3 01.08.2000     1     3     8       1
3         4 01.01.2000     2     2     7       1
4         7 28.01.2000     3     8    15       3
5         8 01.06.2000     3     9     3       1
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and code. I am wondering whether there is also a way to do it in data.tables with subsetting there. I don't know how to translate your cumsum solution to subsetting there. Do you have a suggestion there?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually don't go for the data table approach because the syntax is always more evolved and requires more thought. The dplyr solution flows normally. But if you have a working example in data table and all you need is to include cumsum(), I may try to include that for you.